# Вылезла ошибка на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как исправить ошибку на WP..

Strict Standards: Declaration of magomra_walker_nav_menu::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL) in /home/u/u24444so/kub-zavod.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/m1_template/functions.php on line 0 Strict Standards: Declaration of magomra_walker_nav_menu::start_el() should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = NULL, $id = 0) in /home/u/u24444so/kub-zavod.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/m1_template/functions.php on line 0

Comment: magomra_walker_nav_menu::start_lvl() параметров для метода не хватает

Comment: нужен как минимум один

Comment: Решил таким образом.

Функцию start_lvl(*тут было что-то*) в function.php заменил на start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = ())

Вместо start_el(*тут было что-то) заменил на start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = (), $id = 0)